# Is there a function to decode encoded unicode utf-8 string like from a form?

Tags: forms, unicode, cgi, rebol, rebol3

I want to store some data with a html form and Rebol cgi.  My form looks like this:

```
<form action="test.cgi" method="post" >

     Input:

     <input type="text" name="field"/>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

But for unicode characters like Chinese, I get the encoded form of the data with percent signs, for instance `%E4%BA%BA`.

*(This is for the Chinese character "人" ... its UTF-8 form as a Rebol binary literal is `#{E4BABA}`)*

Is there a function in the system, or an existing library that can decode this directly?    `dehex` does not appear to currently cover this case.  I'm currently decoding this manually by removing the percent signs and constructing the corresponding binary, like this:

```
data: to-string read system/ports/input
print data

;-- this prints "field=%E4%BA%BA"

k-v: parse data "="
print k-v

;-- this prints ["field" "%E4%BA%BA"]

v: append insert replace/all k-v/2 "%" "" "#{" "}"
print v

;-- This prints "#{E4BABA}" ... a string!, not binary!
;-- LOAD will help construct the corresponding binary
;-- then TO-STRING will decode that binary from UTF-8 to character codepoints

write %test.txt to-string load v
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a library called [AltWebForm](http://reb4.me/r3/altwebform) that en/decodes percent-encoded web form data:

```
do http://reb4.me/r3/altwebform
load-webform "field=%E4%BA%BA"
```

The library is described here: [Rebol and Web Forms](http://www.ross-gill.com/page/REBOL_and_Web_Forms).

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be related to ticket #1986, where it is discussed whether this is a "bug" or the Internet changing out from under its own spec:

[Have DEHEX convert UTF-8 sequences from browsers as Unicode](http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=1986).

If you have specific experience on what has become standard in Chinese, and want to weigh in, that would be valuable.

Just as an aside, the specific case above could have been handled in PARSE alternately as:

```
key-value: {field=%E4%BA%BA}

utf8-bytes: copy #{}

either parse key-value [
    copy field-name to {=}
    skip
    some [
        and {%}
        copy enhexed-byte 3 skip (
            append utf8-bytes dehex enhexed-byte
        )
    ]
] [
    print [field-name {is} to string! utf8-bytes]
] [
    print {Malformed input.}
]
```

That will output:

```
field is 人
```

With some comments included:

```
key-value: {field=%E4%BA%BA}

;-- Generate empty binary value by copying an empty binary literal     
utf8-bytes: copy #{}

either parse key-value [

    ;-- grab field-name as the chars right up to the equals sign
    copy field-name to {=}

    ;-- skip the equal sign as we went up to it, without moving "past" it
    skip

    ;-- apply the enclosed rule SOME (non-zero) number of times
    some [
        ;-- match a percent sign as the immediate next symbol, without
        ;-- advancing the parse position
        and {%}

        ;-- grab the next three chars, starting with %, into enhexed-byte
        copy enhexed-byte 3 skip (

            ;-- If we get to this point in the match rule, this parenthesized
            ;-- expression lets us evaluate non-dialected Rebol code to 
            ;-- append the dehexed byte to our utf8 binary
            append utf8-bytes dehex enhexed-byte
        )
    ]
] [
    print [field-name {is} to string! utf8-bytes]
] [
    print {Malformed input.}
]
```

*(Note also that "simple parse" is getting the axe in favor of [enhancements to SPLIT](http://curecode.org/rebol3/ticket.rsp?id=1886).  So writing code like `parse data "="` can now be expressed instead as `split data "="`, or other cool variants if you check them out...samples are in the ticket.)*

Comment: This method is more clarified. Using `load v` to construct the binary is not natural. The two links in http://curecode.org/ is great. I will read them more carefully. There is a little bug in your code, or my version does't support it? The code `{%} -1 skip` can't work in my console(Script Error: Value out of range: -1). I change it to `to {%}` and it works. At last, thank you very much for formatting and reorganization.

Comment: @WayneTsui No problem, sorry about the error... I must have copied that from a version I tried that I thought worked but didn't.  An issue with using TO is that it would advance the parse position up TO that rule... so malformed input like `field=x123\abc%E4BA%BA` would be accepted.  I'll look into how to properly skip backward, but `AND` will ensure that the rule is only fired if percent is the immediate next position without advancing...